# HAPROXY health-check external is not working

Tags: haproxy

```
backend geoserver
balance roundrobin
log global
#option httpclose
#option httplog
#option forceclose 
mode http
#option tcplog

#monitor-uri /tiny
#*************** health check ********************************
option tcpka
option external-check
option log-health-checks
external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp"
#external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
external-check command /bin/true
#external-check command /var/lib/haproxy/ping.sh
timeout queue 60s
timeout server 60s
timeout connect 60s

#************** cookiee *******************************
cookie NV_HAPROXY insert indirect nocache
server web1_Controller_ASHISH 10.10.60.15:9002 check cookie 
web1_Controller_ASHISH
server web2_controller_jagjeet 10.10.60.15:7488 check cookie 
web2_Controller_jagjeet
```

Previously following errors was encountered :

> backend geoserver has no server available!
>   Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Health check for server geoserver/web1_Controller_ASHISH failed, reason: External check error, code: 255, check duration: 0ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Health check for server geoserver/web1_Controller_ASHISH failed, reason: External check error, code: 255, check duration: 0ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Server geoserver/web1_Controller_ASHISH is DOWN. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Server geoserver/web1_Controller_ASHISH is DOWN. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Health check for server geoserver/web2_controller_jagjeet failed, reason: External check error, code: 255, check duration: 0ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Health check for server geoserver/web2_controller_jagjeet failed, reason: External check error, code: 255, check duration: 0ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Server geoserver/web2_controller_jagjeet is DOWN. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> Aug 20 18:02:10 netstorm-ProLiant-ML10 haproxy[54168]: Server geoserver/web2_controller_jagjeet is DOWN. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.

After that I have changed my chroot directory(/var/lib/haproxy) to /etc/haproxy where all my configuration file was stored but still "No server is available to handle this request" error is coming. please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: You can't access *anything* outside the chrooted environment... that's the point of chroot.

Comment: ok, got it .. Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: What is final solution for this problem? Remove "chroot" entry from global? I can't skip this error although the command was copied to chroot directory.